# MySql - How to get datetime of last ALTER TABLE?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way to get datetime of last ALTER TABLE (structure edit) of a table. I'm currently using MySql 5.6. Checking information_schema db I can get only the last generic edit of the table (INSERT, UPDATE, etc.). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not that simple this may give you a start https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91185/how-to-track-only-ddl-statements-executed-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    create_time
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE
    table_schema = 'databasename'
        AND table_name = 'tablename';
```

Above query gives the last table structure edited datetime.

Comment: The manual CREATE_TIME

When the table was created. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html, the question is about ALTER. Are you saying the manual is incorrect?

Comment: don't know about manual, but when I altered a table its create_time changed, maybe MySQL is considering alter table as new table creation, am not sure.